# svg filter to iframe doesn't work in safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, safari

I want to whitebalance filter effect with svg on iframe, and this filter working good in chrome or edge, but in safari, svg filter doesn't work.

https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-nash-e000gl?file=/index.html

this is sample code!

The filter worked fine when applied to an image, but not to an iframe.(in Safari brower)

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please provide a [running code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - this makes debugging way easier

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.